# Refreshing the resources of hidden fragment while locale change inside my app android

Tags: android, fragment, locale, android-fragmentactivity

I have an option to choose language English / Tamil in my android app and this settings is a fragment.

I have another fragment which is hidden and that I have not removed from stack since the requirement is like that. How can i refresh the resources of this hidden fragment when i change the language in the settings fragment.

I am blank and no idea on how to get it done. But I need this to work.

So, please suggest.

Comment: Shared Preferences in android

Comment: I am able to refresh the view for all other fragments and I can see the text changing to the chosen language except this hidden fragment, since it is just hidden.

Comment: no issue if u set Preferences  u can get any where your Preferences if view refresh  or not refresh